# Avoid duplicate entries in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing a small application in android to store basic details about person using SQLite.

I insert data using this function

```
public void insertData(String user,String p_no,SQLiteDatabase db)
    {         
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NAME, user);
            cv.put(PHONE, p_no);
            db.insert("MYTABLE", null, cv);
    }
```

The above function allows duplicate names to be stored.

So I wrote a function that will first check whether a name exits and then enter.

```
public void insertData(String user,String p_no,SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Cursor resultSet=db.rawQuery("select NAME from MYTABLE where NAME = '"+user+"'",null);
        if(resultSet==null)
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NAME, user);
            cv.put(PHONE, p_no);
            db.insert("MYTABLE", null, cv);
        }
        else Toast.makeText(context,user+" already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But the problem is now toast comes up every time I insert meaning even if the row is unique it is not inserted.

**Why resultSet is not null even when there is no such row?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `RawQuery` never returns null cursor, and that's what your checking criteria is, so it is failing always, and trying to add new value in DB.
I am not able to find the documentation where I learned it, but I will update as soon as possible.

You can check if you have values in `cursor` using -

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
```

Answer (score 1):

because it is possible to have an empty cursor. Change your check like

```
if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
```

this way, if the cursor is not null, you check if it contains something too.

Probably this is not the best way to handle duplicates, in my opinion. You should mark your column as `unique`, and use [insertWithConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)), to decide what to do in case you have already an entry with that value

Comment: What are supposed to be the circumstances for the returned cursor being `null` anyway? Reading the source there should always be a valid cursor.

Comment: it is just a sanity check in case the creation of the object fails, in case of memory issues, for instance. Rare cases but still possible

Comment: When there is a memory allocation failure. you get an OOM and no return value at all. They only way to get a `null` return value is when a custom `CursorFactory` returns `null`, but in this case, the particular factory violates the (implicit) protocol. The null check may actually hide an error (making an incorrect return look like "no results").

Comment: I see your point. I am not entirely sure tough. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I'm sorry if  this came over as some kind of harsh criticism, it wasn't. If the return value is `null` something went seriously wrong down the line and that needs to be handled. If it's fine to interpret it as "no results", that's fine, too. It just needs to be thought about.

Comment: it wasn't harsh at all, at least I hadn't that feeling

Comment: @Blackbelt Kindly elaborate on conflict method with some implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
if (resultset.getCount() == 0)
```

Also, create Name as unique key to avoid duplicates. Instead of checking it everytime.

Comment: `raqQuery()` never returns `null` (and there is no `Null`).